# rpy2: Converting a data.frame to a numpy array

Tags: python, r, numpy, bioconductor, rpy2

I have a data.frame in R. It contains a lot of data : gene expression levels from many (125) arrays. I'd like the data in Python, due mostly to my incompetence in R and the fact that this was supposed to be a 30 minute job.

I would like the following code to work. To understand this code, know that the variable `path` contains the full path to my data set which, when loaded, gives me a variable called `immgen`. Know that `immgen` is an object (a Bioconductor `ExpressionSet` object) and that `exprs(immgen)` returns a data frame with 125 columns (experiments) and tens of thousands of rows (named genes). (Just in case it's not clear, this is Python code, using robjects.r to call R code)

```
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
# ... some code to build path
robjects.r("load('%s')"%path) # loads immgen
e = robjects.r['data.frame']("exprs(immgen)")
expression_data = np.array(e)
```

This code runs, but `expression_data` is simply `array([[1]])`.

I'm pretty sure that `e` doesn't represent the data frame generated by `exprs()` due to things like:

```
In [40]: e._get_ncol()
Out[40]: 1

In [41]: e._get_nrow()
Out[41]: 1
```

But then again who knows? Even if `e` did represent my data.frame, that it doesn't convert straight to an array would be fair enough - a data frame has more in it than an array (rownames and colnames) and so maybe life shouldn't be this easy. However I still can't work out how to perform the conversion. The documentation is a bit too terse for me, though my limited understanding of the headings in the docs implies that this should be possible.

Anyone any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why going through a data.frame when 'exprs(immgen)' returns a /matrix/ and your end goal is to have your data in a matrix ?

Passing the matrix to numpy is straightforward (and can even be made without making a copy):
http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/numpy.html#from-rpy2-to-numpy

This should beat in both simplicity and efficiency the suggestion of going through text representation of numerical data in flat files as a way to exchange data.

You seem to be working with bioconductor classes, and might be interested in the following:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpy2-bioconductor-extensions/

Comment: argh you're right. It is a matrix. That's brilliant, thanks. Just so the solution is clear, i can do:
    e = np.array(robjects.r('exprs(immgen)'))
and now e is a numpy array with all my floating point numbers in it. Thanks Laurent! I am interested in the bioC rpy2 stuff, but can't get it to install. A question for the support list though maybe...

Answer (score 7):

This is the most straightforward and reliable way i've found to to transfer a data frame from R to Python.

To begin with, I think exchanging the data through the R bindings is an unnecessary complication. R provides a simple method to export data, likewise, NumPy has decent methods for data import. The file format is the only common interface required here.

```
data(iris)
iris$Species = unclass(iris$Species)

write.table(iris, file="/path/to/my/file/np_iris.txt", row.names=F, sep=",")

# now start a python session
import numpy as NP

fpath = "/path/to/my/file/np_iris.txt"

A = NP.loadtxt(fpath, comments="#", delimiter=",", skiprows=1)

# print(type(A))
# returns: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

print(A.shape)
# returns: (150, 5)

print(A[1:5,])
# returns: 
 [[ 4.9  3.   1.4  0.2  1. ]
  [ 4.7  3.2  1.3  0.2  1. ]
  [ 4.6  3.1  1.5  0.2  1. ]
  [ 5.   3.6  1.4  0.2  1. ]]
```

According to the Documentation (and my own experience for what it's worth) *loadtxt* is the preferred method for conventional data import.

You can also pass in to *loadtxt* a tuple of data types (the argument is *dtypes*), one item in the tuple for each column. Notice 'skiprows=1' to step over the column headers (for *loadtxt* rows are indexed from 1, columns from 0).

Finally, i converted the dataframe factor to integer (which is actually the underlying data type for factor) prior to exporting--'unclass' is probably the easiest way to do this.

If you have big data (ie, don't want to load the entire data file into memory but still need to access it)  **NumPy's memory-mapped data structure** ('memmap') is a good choice:

```
from tempfile import mkdtemp
import os.path as path

filename = path.join(mkdtemp(), 'tempfile.dat')

# now create a memory-mapped file with shape and data type 
# based on original R data frame:
A = NP.memmap(fpath, dtype="float32", mode="w+", shape=(150, 5))

# methods are ' flush' (writes to disk any changes you make to the array), and 'close'
# to write data to the memmap array (acdtually an array-like memory-map to 
# the data stored on disk)
A[:] = somedata[:]
```

Comment: Thanks Doug! This is the solution I had settled on too - the only problem being that the resulting files are +50MB which is sort of OK, but seems a touch clunky! I kind of want the rpy2 bindings to let me write a function that says `array,colnames,rownames = from_df("data.frame()"`.

Comment: in that case (big data) i would just use NumPy's memory-mapped data structure, to avoid loading the entire thing into RAM. Editing my answer w/ example.